# How i can implement authorization on controller base when i have no model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am using rails 3 with cancan gem.And now i am trying to implement authorization  in

administrator controller while i have no administrator model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have faced this problem and after all implement this solution I hope it will work fine for

you.

In controller you should authorize like this

```
   authorize_resource :class => false
```

In ability.rb

```
    can [:index,:list,:report], :administrator
```

Try it......

Answer (score 0):

You can define an ability admin model that isn't backed by a database.
You would be defining abilities to access the other models anyway.